# Implement a Monte Carlo Simulation Method to Estimate an Integral in R

Tags: r

I am trying to implement a Monte carlo simulation method to estimate an integral in R. However, I still get wrong answer. My code is as follows:

```r
f <- function(x){
  ((cos(x))/x)*exp(log(x)-3)^3
}
t <- integrate(f,0,1)

n <- 10000 #Assume we conduct 10000 simulations
int_gral <- Monte_Car(n)
int_gral
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing Monte-Carlo here. Monte-Carlo is a simulation method that helps you approximating integrals using sums/mean based on random variables.

You should do something in this flavor (you might have to verify that it's correct to say that the mean of the f output can approximates your integral:

```r
f <- function(n){
  x <- runif(n)
  return(
    ((cos(x))/x)*exp(log(x)-3)^3
  )
}
int_gral <- mean(f(10000))
```

What your code does is taking a number `n` and return `((cos(n))/n)*exp(log(n)-3)^3` ; there is no randomness in that

## Update

Now, to get a more precise estimates, you need to replicate this step `K` times. Rather than using a `loop`, you can use `replicate` function:

```r
K <- 100
dist <- data.frame(
  int = replicate(K, mean(f(10000)))
)
```

You get a distribution of estimators for your integral :

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dist) + geom_histogram(aes(x = int, y = ..density..))
```

[image]

and you can use `mean` to have a numerical value:

```r
mean(dist$int)
# [1] 2.95036e-05
```

You can evaluate the precision of your estimates with

```r
sd(dist$int)
# [1] 2.296033e-07
```

Here it is small because *N* is already large, giving you a good precision of first step.

Comment: Hello, I think I need to be clear. I need to get the numerical integral of the function ((cos(x))/x)*exp(log(x)-3)^3). The lower limit is 0 while the upper limit is Infinity. I need to do the integration using Monte Carlo Method.

Comment: I understood your problem. You should have a look at some resources on the subject, e.g. [that](http://www.math.chalmers.se/Stat/Grundutb/CTH/tms150/1415/MC_20141008.pdf). You first need to draw a random variable covering the support of your distribution (e.g. for a [0,1] a uniform distribution can be used) and then perform mean. `n` is the number of draws for your distribution, e.g. 10 000 in my example.

Comment: @MicahOndiwa The integral from 0 to infinifty does not converge.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have actually managed to change the code. kindly check if I am in the right track: f <- function(x){
  ((cos(x))/x)*exp(log(x)-3)^3
}

set.seed(234)
n<-10000
for (i in 1:10000) {
  x<-runif(n)
  I<-sum(f(x))/n
}
I

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to change the codes as follows. Kindly confirm to me that I am doing the right thing.

regards.

```
f <- function(x){
      ((cos(x))/x)*exp(log(x)-3)^3
    }
    set.seed(234)
    n<-10000
    for (i in 1:10000) {
      x<-runif(n)
      I<-sum(f(x))/n
    }
    I
```

Comment: Yes you've got it right. However, you should dissociate in notations *N* (size of your *U[0,1]* vector) and the number of replications (usually denoted *K*). Look at my edited answer for a more elegant approach than a `for` loop. If it corresponds to what you were looking for, you can accept it

Comment: Nice, thanks. I don't think you accepted it yet, [see here if you need guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck with your Monte Carlo !

Comment: Acceptance. Thanks for sharing the guidlines