# How to set up a Monte Carlo simulation in an ODE to estimate uncertainty?

Tags: r, ode, montecarlo, desolve

I am aiming to do a Monte Carlo simulation of my ODE to see the variance of possible outcomes and graph the solutions to visualize the results for the entire time-sequence. However, I am struggling to set up the simulation and can't seem to find solutions for my specific problem. Previously I've used the package pksensi, but I'm using R version 3.4.4 and not able to update on this computer - so pksensi is not available. I have also seen examples using the FME-package using the modCRL-function. I've followed and run this example: https://rdrr.io/cran/FME/man/modCRL.html, however I struggle to understand how this is set up and the output. I've also tried seeing simpler models for potential solutions like this link [Implement a Monte Carlo Simulation Method to Estimate an Integral in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61337735/implement-a-monte-carlo-simulation-method-to-estimate-an-integral-in-r), but I still can't find a solution.

I have a code showing what I've tried - I get errors and understand that this is not set up correctly, but hopefully my logic is understandable. I have never set up a Monte Carlo simulation before (besides pksensi), so any help as to how to set it up would be extremely appreciated.

```
library(deSolve)

months <- seq(0, 144, 1)
all.df <- data.frame(months, c.weight = c(3.5,  4,  5,  5,  6, 7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 52, 54, 55))

model <- function(times, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    
    if (times <= 5) {
      volume <- (((0.2 * times) * c.weight[times+1]) * 30)
      transferred <- pm * volume
    } else if (times > 5 & times <= 14) {
      volume <- ((0.1 * c.weight[times+1]) * 30)
      transferred <- pm * volume
    } else {
      transferred <- 0
    }
    
    intake.c <- (dose * c.weight[times+1])
    elimination.c <- concentration * vd * c.weight[times+1] * log(2) / (halflife * 12)
    
    concentration <- (intake.c + transferred - elimination.c) / (vd * c.weight[times+1])
    
    list(c(concentration))
    
  })
}

#Following you can see my attempt to perform a Monte Carlo simulation with specific parameters using rnorm()
#The state can vary as well as the different parameters in params
state <- c(concentration = 0.5 * rnorm(1000, mean = 0.7, sd = 0.2)) #parameter to be tested
params <- list(vd = rnorm(1000, mean = 0.2, sd = 0.02), #parameter to be tested
               pm = rnorm(1000, mean = 0.05, sd = 0.03), #parameter to be tested
               halflife = rnorm(1000, mean = 4, sd = 2), #parameter to be tested
               dose = 0.001,
               c.weight = all.df$c.weight)
out <- as.data.frame(ode(y = state, times = months, func = model, parms = params))
```

Comment: Instead of homegrown approach, have you considered [this package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/uncertainty/uncertainty.pdf)? Another option, which incorporates your homegrown MC is `metRology::uncertMC`. I found a [PowerPoint with explanations regarding its use](https://www.eurachem.org/images/stories/workshops/2019_11_MU/pdf/PL5-03_R_metRology_Ellison.pdf), as well. (I didn't look particularly close as to whether the PPT was useful, though.)

Comment: Monte Carlo methods can be used for different tasks. `modCRL` can be used for a global sensitivity analysis. It can easily be set up without additional packages. A related question was answered [a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72914861/3677576).  Or, here another [guide](http://dkneis.github.io/r-related/sensitivityGuide.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the approach from [an answer given a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72914861/3677576), we may write a function that encapsulates random number generation and model simulation. Then we can call this in a loop or with `replicate` or `lapply`. The result is then a list of simulations that can be further analyzed. We can start with a plot. Here, the first argument of the `plot` function is an output of `ode` and the second a list of `ode` outputs. The first can be a deterministic reference simulation, here we use just the first case:

```r
simulation <- function() {
  
  ## use only a single concentration, i.e. set rnorm(n=1, ....)
  state <- c(concentration = 0.5 * rnorm(1, mean = 0.7, sd = 0.2))
  params <- list(vd = rnorm(1, mean = 0.2, sd = 0.02),
                 pm = rnorm(1, mean = 0.05, sd = 0.03),
                 halflife = rnorm(1, mean = 4, sd = 2),
                 dose = 0.001,
                 c.weight = all.df$c.weight)
  ode(y = state, times = months, func = model, parms = params)
}

## here we use 1:10 for testing, but you can also use 1:1000 if you want
outlist <- lapply(1:10, function(i) simulation())

## plot results
plot(outlist[[1]], outlist)
```

Further ideas by request in form of a new SO question.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add two examples made following the link  @tpetzoldt posted: [Simulating ODE model for different initial conditions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914861/simulating-ode-model-for-different-initial-conditions-in-r). Note if N is too high, something strange happens with the model - I suspect if it runs with the "wrong" parameter values the graph is L-formed.

Example 1 following code by @Ben Bolker using a for-loop:

```
N <- 10
res <- list()
for (i in 1:N) {
  ## pick new initial conditions
  cur_states <- c(concentration = 0.5 * rnorm(1, mean = 0.78, sd = 0.15))
  
  params <- list(vd = rnorm(1, mean = 0.170, sd = 0.026),
                 pm = rnorm(1, mean = 0.058, sd = 0.035),
                 halflife = rnorm(1, mean = 3.8, sd = 1.7),
                 dose = 0.001,
                 c.weight = all.df$c.weight)
  
  ## run model and attach index column to the matrix
  res[[i]] <-
    cbind(run = i,
          ode(y = cur_states, times = months, func = model,
              parms = params, method="lsoda")
    )
}

# combine individual runs into one long matrix
res_final <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,res))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = res_final, aes(x = time, y = concentration, group = run)) +
  geom_line()
```

Example 2 following code by @tpetzoldt using replicate:

```
state <- c(concentration = 0.5)
params <- list(vd = 0.2,
               pm = 0.05,
               halflife = 4,
               dose = 0.001,
               c.weight = all.df$c.weight)
out <- ode(y = state, times = months, func = model, parms = params)

N <- 10
res <- replicate(N, ode(y = c(concentration = 0.5 * rnorm(1, mean = 0.78, sd = 0.15)),
                        times = months,
                        func = model,
                        parms = list(vd = rnorm(1, mean = 0.170, sd = 0.026),
                                     pm = rnorm(1, mean = 0.058, sd = 0.035),
                                     halflife = rnorm(1, mean = 3.8, sd = 1.7),
                                     dose = 0.001,
                                     c.weight = all.df$c.weight)),
                 simplify = FALSE)

plot(out, res)
```